# On Lyapunov stability of a solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

I have recently encountered the following exercise: prove or disprove that the solution of the ODE $\dot x = -\frac{2x}{t} + t^2$ that satisfies $x(1)=1$ is Lyapunov stable. I have proved that the solution is stable, however, the correct answer *(as per my teacher)* is the opposite.

My proof is as follows:

$$\begin{aligned}
\dot x &= -\frac{2x}{t} + t^2 \\
t^2\dot x + 2xt &= t^4 \\
t^2\dot x + x(t^2)' &= t^4 \\
(t^2 x)' &= t^4 \\
t^2 x &= \frac{t^5}{5} + C \\
x &= \frac{t^3}{5} + \frac{C}{t^2} \\
\end{aligned}$$

The solution that satisfies $x(1)=1$ is $x=\varphi(t)=\cfrac{t^3}{5} + \cfrac{4}{5t^2}$.

The definition of Lyapunov stability:
$$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \ \ \exists \delta > 0 \ \ |x(t_0) - \varphi(t_0)|< \delta \implies \forall t > t_0 \ \ |x(t) - \varphi(t)| < \varepsilon$$
$$|x(t_0) - \varphi(t_0)|< \delta \implies \left|\frac{1}{5} + \frac{C}{t^2} - \frac{1}{5} - \frac{4}{5}\right| < \delta \implies \left|C - \frac{4}{5}\right| < \delta$$
$$|x(t) - \varphi(t)| < \varepsilon \implies \left|\frac{t^3}{5} + \frac{C}{t^2} - \frac{t^3}{5} - \frac{4}{5t^2}\right| < \varepsilon \implies \left|\frac{1}{t^2}\left(C-\frac{4}{5}\right)\right| < \varepsilon$$
Let $\delta=\varepsilon$. Then
$$\left|\frac{1}{t^2}\left(C-\frac{4}{5}\right)\right| < \varepsilon \implies \varepsilon\left|\frac{1}{t^2}\right| < \varepsilon$$
, which holds.

Comment: In the second line you shoud have $=t^3$ instead of $=t^4$.

Comment: Or better, the $t^4$ is correct, but the coefficient for $\dot x$ is $t^2$. The following lines are correct, so that this is likely a typo.

Comment: Even though you have made two simple mistakes in deriving the solution of the ODE, you obtained the correct answer. The solution is not bounded due to $t^3$ which implies that the system is not Lyapunov stable.

Comment: @BilalJafarKaraki How does the solution not being bounded by $t^3$ imply that it's not Lyapunov stable? It doesn't seem trivial from the definition.

Comment: Stability definition means that the solution will stay bounded by an arbitrary small $\epsilon$-ball. The appearance of $t^3$ implies that the solution is growing which contradicts the sense of stability. So for any $\epsilon$  you chose, the solution will leave it after a considerable amount of time.

Comment: @BilalJafarKaraki Do you have a reference for your definition? It doesn't seem to match the one I'm using.

Comment: I will write a detailed answer.

Comment: Note that the initial condition is given, the question could be related to the continuous dependence on initial conditions. For this case, you can read Sec 3.2 in Nonlinear systems, Hassan Khalil 3ed.

Answer (score 1):

You obtained the following equation
$$\frac{d}{dt}(t^2 x)  = t^4 \quad (1) $$
then you found the following general solution:
$$t^2 x(t) = \frac{t^5}{5} + C $$
which is also true, but you can not treat $C$ as an initial condition of the original differential equation. To use the defintion of stability, you sould integrate both sides of Equaiton (1) form $t_0$ to $t\geq t_0$. Integrating (1) gives:

$$t^2x(t)-t_0^2x(t_0)=\frac{1}{5}t^5-\frac{1}{5}t_0^5$$

or equivilanetly:
$$x(t)=\frac{t_0^2}{t^2}x(t_0)+\frac{1}{5}t^3-\frac{1}{5t^2}t_0^5$$

To prove the stability, the following should hold for any   $\epsilon$ .....
$$\|x(t)-x(t_0)||=\bigg\|(\frac{t_0^2}{t^2}-1)x(t_0)+\frac{1}{5}t^3-\frac{1}{5t^2}t_0^5\bigg\|\leq\epsilon \qquad (2)$$
But if there exists at least one $\epsilon$ such that Equaiton (2) is not satisfied for all initial conditions then the system is not stable. Slecet $\epsilon =1$, then one can see that $\bigg\|(\frac{t_0^2}{t^2}-1)x(t_0)+\frac{1}{5}t^3-\frac{1}{5t^2}t_0^5\bigg\|$ is not bounded because of $t^3$.